# Java Virtual Machine stops responding with no known reason

Tags: java, loops, crash, libgdx

After exporting my project from Eclipse into an executable Java program, the program stops responding randomly. I can't find any specific event or action that causes it. The only reason I can think of it happening is an endless loop however the only one I have is this:

```
for(int i =0;i<pipes.length;i++){
    if((powerUp.bound.overlaps(pipes[i].bounds)|| (powerUp.bound.overlaps(pipes[i].bounds2)))|| (powerUp.bound.overlaps(blocks[i].bound))){
        powerUp.position.y=(float) ((HEIGHT/4)+((HEIGHT/2)* (Math.random())));
        i=0;
    }
}
```

Which basically makes sure the powerUp doesn't spawn within objects, there is plenty of free space for them to spawn in.

There are no other continuous loops in my code so are there other reasons for a "stopped responding" error?

Comment: It sounds like one or more of your "powerUp.bound.overlaps()" stays "true" and keeps resetting your counter to "0".  The JVM isn't unresponsive - you've programmed an infinite loop!

Comment: But what should be happening is that the position of the power up is randomly changed every time it overlaps so eventually it should be it open space, right?

Comment: SUGGESTIONS: 1) Execute your program in an IDE debugger (for example, Eclipse or Android Studio) and look at the threads/thread stacks when the "hang" occurs; 2) Write "printf" or "toast" statements before/after your "fo"r loop to see if the "hang" occurs inside the loop; 3) run [strace](http://hokstad.com/5-simple-ways-to-troubleshoot-using-strace) or a similar OS-level tool to see the last thing your program did before it hung

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to figure out *where* the hang is occurring. Remember - it's entirely possibly it has nothing to do with the "for" loop: it could be anywhere.

It's a pretty safe bet the "hang" is an application error, not a "JVM bug".

SUGGESTIONS:

1. Execute your program in an IDE debugger (for example, Eclipse or Android Studio) and look at the threads/thread stacks when the "hang" occurs;
2. Alternatively, step through your program in the debugger until you encounter the hang.
3. Write "printf" or "toast" statements before/after your "for" loop to verify whether or not the "hang" actually occurs inside the loop;
4. Run [strace](http://hokstad.com/5-simple-ways-to-troubleshoot-using-strace), [Windows Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) or a similar OS-level tool to see the last thing your program did before it hung.
5. If you have any system and/or application logs, be sure to check them.

I have no idea what your target environment is.  But on the off chance it might be Android, this article might help:

- http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Good luck - and please post back what you find!

Comment: *"It's a pretty safe bet ..."* - Odds of 1000 to 1 on would be appropriate :-)

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, i tested my program and it is the for loop, i used your output method to determine this. How can I fix the problem? I don't even understand how/why its happening.

Comment: Never mind I have found that the available space for it to spawn is in fact incorrect, sorry for the long post and thank you very much for the help